# Does dependency property deserialization trigger the callback?

Tags: c#, wpf

Let's say I have a boolean DP with a default value of False and a register callback OnDPChanged. The DP is serialized every time the app exits. On app startup I deserialize the DP. In which cases will OnDPChanged fire?

If my understanding is correct then on every startup the DP is created with the default value. After which the new deserialized value is applied and if it differs from the default the callback is triggered ???

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how you serialize. The XML serializer serializes properties. This means that it e.g. uses the `Text` property of `TextBox`. However, binary serializers serialize (private) fields.

When the properties are serialized, the property setter is used and yes, the event will fire. When the fields are serialized, the raw internal data will be set without going through the setters and the object won't know they have been set, so it can't fire the event.